# DataAdaptor.Fill error

Tags: sql, vb.net, syntax-error, dataadapter

i coppied some code from [**HERE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.bindingsource.aspx) but i'm getting an error: "incorrect syntax near ')'.
But i can't see anything wrong with this code

```
Dim conString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\users.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(conString)
        con.Open()
        Try
            Dim dataAdapter1 As New SqlDataAdapter( _
                New SqlCommand("SELECT subject, info, username, status FROM(problems) WHERE (username =" & userName & ")", con))
            Dim ds As New DataSet("DataSetMyProbs")
            ds.Tables.Add("UserProbs")
            dataAdapter1.Fill(ds.Tables("UserProbs")) '//This is where i get the error'
            Me.bsMyProblems.DataSource = ds.Tables("UserProbs")
            Dim dataAdapter2 As New SqlDataAdapter( _
                New SqlCommand("SELECT dep, pcid, username, status, extraInfo FROM(deployments) WHERE (username = " & userName & ")", con))
            ds.Tables.Add("UsersDepl")
            dataAdapter2.Fill(ds.Tables("UserDepl"))
            Me.bsMyDepl.DataSource = ds.Tables("UserDepl")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that may because of your query, is your parameter userName a string? you may need to put a single quote for a string, also give a space in between "FROM" and the table name

```
Dim dataAdapter1 As New SqlDataAdapter( _
            New SqlCommand("SELECT subject, info, username, status FROM [problems] WHERE (username ='" & userName & "')", con))
```

Comment: thanks, just one thing... 
i'm not getting errors now, but i loads the wrong query, i really don't get this. I hate SQL, mysql is much easier

Comment: ?? could you help me with this please? why does it always load 1 particular user even if i send other users in the query. Could this be the bindingnavigator or is it something else

Comment: When you send other users in the query, do you use IN? or just call the function again with different parameter?

Comment: Can you provide more codes on how you send other users in the query as well as showing your result?

Comment: well, the deal is this, you get a login form. you login, the login name gets send to the main form and there this happens on load. Should i be using IN? and how in case yes

Comment: it depends on your function, if you only need 1 user information, then would be better using **=**. otherwise if you need more than users information populate into your data table, then **IN** would be better. so what is your preference in your case?

Comment: in this particular case i need all records of one and only one user so i believe it would  be =

Comment: Then you need to make sure there is no space in your username

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your SQL statement

It should be:

```
SELECT subject, info, username, status FROM [problems] ....
```